# not showing the checkout button when the cart is 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I will like to not display the CHECKOUT button when the cart is 0.

I added this line but it is not working when the Ajax is running.  I added 1 product to the cart,
I removed it.   The Checkout button is showing up.   I will like to not see the checkout when the cart is 0 or empty.  Thanks

Index.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Panier")',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                     $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                     $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                     $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                     $.get('@Url.Action("CartSummary", "Panier")');
                     $('#content').html(result);
                 },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
             }
             });
             return false;
         });

     });
 </script>

 <h3>
     <em>Visualisation </em> du panier:
 </h3>


 @if (Model.CartTotal != 0)    <== I added this line
 {
      <p class="button">
          @Html.ActionLink("Paiement >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
      </p>  
 }

 <div id="update-message">
 </div>

 <div id="content">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <th>
                 Produit
             </th>
             <th>
                 Prix (unitaire)
             </th>
             <th>
                 Quantite
             </th>
             <th></th>
         </tr>

         @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
         {
             <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
                 <td>
                     @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                           item.ProduitId }, null)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @item.Produit.Prix
                 </td>
                 <td id="item-count-@item.PanierId">
                     @item.Quantite
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier 
                        >> </a>
                </td>
             </tr>
         }

         <tr>
             <td>
                 Total
             </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td id="cart-total">
                 @Model.CartTotal
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

PanierController.cs

```
    public ActionResult CartSummary()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();

        return PartialView("CartSummary");
    }
```

CartSummary.cshtml

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Panier(" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")", "Index","Panier", new { id = "cart-
  status" })
```

Output of Cart right now

```
 Cart:

 Checkout >>
 -----------

 Product ABC has been remove from your shopping cart.
```

Output of Cart should be like this

```
 Cart:

 Product ABC has been remove from your shopping cart.
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion might be:

```
                 $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                 $('#cart-status').attr('data-cart-count', result.CartCount);
```

in css:

```
    #cart-status[data-cart-count="0"]
    {
    display:none;
    }
```

Or maybe a conditional in your javascript to not output the Cart () text when result.CartCount is zero:

```
   if (result.CartCount > 0) {
     $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
   }
```

Comment: this is the line I don't want to see "@Html.ActionLink("Paiement >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")" not the CartCount.   If you have any idea on how to do this let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly an all too common confusion. Your problem lies in understanding the Server-Client relationship. ASP.NET processing happens *server-side*, while JavaScript processing happens *client-side*. These are two totally separate phases in the process, so you can't test for the cart being empty with Razor *server-side*, if it's not actually empty until you remove something via AJAX *client-side*.

The solution then, is to check if the cart is empty with JS and remove or hide the button with JS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  any way we can hide the button in JS ?

Comment: Is it possible to provide me an example of code to perform the solution you propose ?  I am new in Jquery, Ajax. Thanks